# How to delay animation on CSS? I've tried animation-delay. Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've created really good slides in CSS but I want them to show after another. For example, I've got this animation below and no matter how higher I use animation-delay parameter, it simply won't work. I need this to work as a second slide. It must appear 30s after the first one.

```
  .slideInLeft2 {  /* do slide 2*/
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInLeft2;
  animation-name: slideInLeft2;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 111s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-animation: fadein 3s ease-in; /* Opera */
  animation: fadein 3s ease-in-out;
    }
  animation-delay: 11s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft2 {
  0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  }
  }
  @keyframes slideInLeft2 {
  0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-400%);
  transform: translateX(-400%);
  visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
  {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
  }
```

Comment: Re your tags: are you looking for a javascript/jquery solution??

Comment: Also, there's an extra `}` above your `animation-delay: 11s;`... that'll screw things up

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a typo, you set it to 111 seconds on line 7...

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 111s;
```

It should be -

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 11s;
```

Answer (score 0):

you override your code with

```
animation: fadein 3s ease-in-out;
```

you should put delay in this part too, like this:

```
animation: fadein 3s ease-in-out 111s;
```